# CSS - image with overlays/background blurred diagonal

Tags: css, background-image, css-filters

I want that the parts that are "whited" to get the image blurred.

I've tried using pseudo elements ::after and ::before to add the overlays but could only blurred the overlay.

tried with borders 2nd example codepen, but no sucess because with the transparent it creates a "square".

https://codepen.io/giventofly/pen/RQpqYZ

```
.hero-image {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(46, 51, 82, 0.6) 100%, transparent 0), linear-gradient(125deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 35%, transparent 0), linear-gradient(-55deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%, transparent 0),
                    url('https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/NU6lcSN3DGmjF7NhZp6ixY3HxgQ=/0x0:1620x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:1620x1080)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/46510678/Tarmogoyf_DGM_1920x1080_Wallpaper.0.0.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;   
  z-index: 10;
}

<div class="hero-image"></div>
```

I only want to blur the part of the image that is "behind" the white linear-gradient

Comment: i edited my answer, as at the start i understand it bad ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure someone can refine this approach a bit, but the main takeaways are:

- Include the image twice in a container element.
- Stack the two images.
- Blur one and place it on the bottom.
- Use `clip-path` on the top image to display the non-blurred region.
- Insert a frost layer (transparent white) with a pseudo element of the container element between the two images.
- Control layering with positioning and z-index.

```css
.img-overlay {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-overlay::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 );
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-overlay img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur( 3px);
  z-index: 0;
}

.img-overlay img:last-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-overlay">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/400/400?image=16">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/400/400?image=16">
</div>
```

Comment: so exactly like i did, no ? :)

Comment: They are very similar. I began my post when you had deleted yours. I walked away for a short time, completed it and published. Upon page refresh, you had updated your answer and undeleted it. The main difference is how images are included (`<img>` vs `background-image`) and how the color overlay is created (pseudo-element vs `linear-gradient`).

Comment: going to choose this as the best answer because of the approach. can only upvote the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use clip-path for this. The idea is to have two similar layer, the top with the clip-path to show only the needed part and keep the blur on the bottom layer visible. You can switch the blur between both element if you want to blur the middle part instead:

```css
.hero-image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-image:after,
.hero-image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: center/cover no-repeat;
  background-image: 
   linear-gradient(rgba(46, 51, 82, 0.6) 100%, transparent 0), 
   linear-gradient(125deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 35%, transparent 0), 
   linear-gradient(-55deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%, transparent 0), 
   url('https://picsum.photos/id/1024/800/800');
}

.hero-image:before {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.hero-image:after {
  clip-path: polygon(45% 0, 97% 0, 68% 100%, 16% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image"></div>
```